# List all folders, where users (except admin) have allow full access

Tags: powershell, acl, fileserver

At our company file server we used to have loose permissions several years ago.
Meaning, there are folders where users tend to have full permission. This is a bad thing (user playing with rights, locking out the system (and the backup with it) and only giving themselves access.

My goal:

Scan the fileserver folder by folder (files would be too much) and output

- folder full path
- Security Identity Reference

if someone has fullaccess besides domain admins or system.

The output would be fine as:

```
Path, ACL
E:\share\projectfolder, Domain\10JohnDoe
E:\share\commonfolder, Domain\Everyone
...
```

This is what I have, but it is not nearly enough:

```bsh
##define variable
$path = "E:\Share"
## begin script

foreach ($file in Get-Childitem $path -Recurse -Directory) {
    if (Get-Acl $file.FullName |
        select -ExpandProperty Access |
        where {$_.IdentityReference -notlike "AT\Domain Admins" -and
            $_.IdentityReference -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -and
            $_.AccessControlType -like "Allow" -and
            $_.FileSystemRights -like "FullControl"}
    ) {
        Write-Host $file.FullName >> e:\check_acl.txt
        Get-Acl $file.FullName |
            select -ExpandProperty Access |
            where {$_.IdentityReference -notlike "AT\Domain Admins" -and
                $_.IdentityReference -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -and
                $_.AccessControlType -like "Allow" -and
                $_.FileSystemRights -like "FullControl"
            } >> e:\check_acl.txt
    }
}
```

But I guess, I cannot get the output (into file!) like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Write-Host` only displays text to the console, it can't be saved. `Get-Acl >> check_acl.txt` will write the whole "object" and not just the identityreference. What you want is to create a custom object with a Path and ACL (identityreference)-property and export it to csv.

I've also simplified your identity-exclusion and changed the if-test to a foreach-loop so you don't have to run the whole `Get-ACL`-line twice.

Try this:

```
##define variable
$path = "E:\Share"
$ExcludeUsers = 'AT\Domain Admins','NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM','AT\AT-IT','AT\01STREW','AT\01BRUND','AT\01KNAFP','AT\01BECKC'
## begin script

#Create regex-pattern to match all excluded users
$ExcludeUsersRegex = ($ExcludeUsers | % { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'


Get-Childitem $path -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_

    Get-Acl -Path $file.FullName |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access |
    Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -notmatch $ExcludeUsersRegex -and $_.AccessControlType -eq "Allow" -and $_.FileSystemRights -eq "FullControl"} |
    ForEach-Object {
        #Foreach ACL
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            Path = $file.FullName
            ACL = $_.IdentityReference
        }
    }
} | Select-Object -Property Path, ACL | Export-Csv e:\check_acl.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output:

```
"Path","ACL"
"C:\Users\frode\Desktop\TEST\YES","CONTOSO\frode"
"C:\Users\frode\Desktop\TEST\YES","CONTOSO\FrodesOtherAccount"
```

Comment: Hello Frode,
this really seems to do... I thank you!

of course without real understanding of the object and the programming language itself it is hard...

Comment: Most access rights use to be inherited (`IsInherited` property) so it would be worth testing the `$path` directory itself as well in addition to its subfolders. Here are some useful links for @DavidBrunner: [Understanding Streams, Redirection, and Write-Host in PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) and [Write-Host Considered Harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)