# Exclude specific users when listing Windows folder permissions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to list all users who have access to a specific directory and the subfolders in this directory.

I've found this [website](https://petri.com/how-to-get-ntfs-file-permissions-using-powershell) that shows me how to do this pretty well. But I want to modify this script slightly so I can exclude certain built-in Windows users from the output.

So I found another link on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825648/list-all-folders-where-users-except-admin-have-allow-full-access) that shows how to exclude a list of users from the results. But when I add the `-notmatch` to the existing PS script, the Group/User changes from the actual username to True or False for some reason.

What can I do to have this script filter out the users in the `$ignore` variable and have the Group/User show the username?

```
$ignore = @('BUILTIN\Administrators','CREATOR OWNER')
$ExcludeUsersRegex = ($ignore | % { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

$FolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "D:\MSSQL" -Recurse -Force
$Output = @()
ForEach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access) {
$Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=$Folder.FullName;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference -notmatch $ExcludeUsersRegex;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
#$Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=$Folder.FullName;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
$Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties            
}
}
$Output | Out-GridView
```

Comment: `ForEach($Access in ($Acl.Access|Where{$_.IdentityReference -notmatch $ExcludeUsersRegex})) {` filters out the accesses that match a specific user name.

Comment: Thanks - if you post as an answer, I will be glad to accept and mark as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter at the loop level, so undesirable users aren't iterated through the loop.

```
ForEach($Access in ($Acl.Access|Where{$_.IdentityReference -notmatch $ExcludeUsersRegex})) {
```

That filters out the accesses that match a specific user name.